# npm adduser fails with 404 not found

Tags: npm

I'm trying to publish to a private registry, but I need to add a user first. When I try:

`npm adduser --registry=http://my-registry:8081`

I get the following prompt/output:

> Username: rjohns
>
> Password:
>
> Email: (this IS public) rjohns@email.com
>
> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! /Users/rjohns/.npm/_logs/2018-02-09T23_30_02_911Z-debug.log

The log mentioned shows:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'adduser',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '--registry=http://my-registry:8081' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@5.5.1
>
> 3 info using node@v8.9.3
>
> 4 verbose stack Error: Not Found
>
> 4 verbose stack     at fetch.defaults.then.then.result
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/index.js:203:19)
>
> 4 verbose stack     at
>
> 4 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>
> 5 verbose cwd /Users/rjohns/Developer/hybrid-plugin copy
>
> 6 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
>
> 7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "adduser"
>   "--registry=http://my-registry:8081"
>
> 8 verbose node v8.9.3
>
> 9 verbose npm  v5.5.1
>
> 10 error code E404
>
> 11 error 404 Not Found
>
> 12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

What is going on here?